# String with double qoutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need to pass strings with double quote as a parameter to a proxy method as below:

```
public void CallProxyMethod()
{
   //SomeProxyClass derives from Systems.Collections.Generic.List<string>
   var parameters = new SomeProxyClass() {"parameter1", "paramter2", "parameter3"};
   SomeProxyMethod(parameters);
}
```

These parameter values are read from config file.

```
<add key=Parameters" value="parameter1, parameter2, parameter3"/>
```

I tried splitting the config values by comma and adding double quotes to them but I end up with the following values in the **SomeProxyClass** above:

"\"parameter1\"", "\"paramter2\"", "\"parameter3\"".

The values I need in the class are:

"parameter1", "paramter2", "parameter3".

How can I convert **"parameter1, parameter2, parameter3"** to
**"parameter1", "paramter2", "parameter3"** in C#?

Comment: The `value` attribute cannot hold more than one string. `value = "param1","param2","param3"` is invalid and will cause errors.

Comment: @TravisJ TI have `value = "parameter1, parameter2, parameter3"` , not `value = "parameter1", "parameter2", "parameter3"`

Comment: Why bother with quotes? You get the value from the config file as a string; when you split it on a comma, you get an array of strings. Pass those to your proxy class, or use `parameters.AddRange(splitString);` or whatever.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Mike, I tried your approach and the parameters get passed successfully to `SomeProxyClass`, but strangely, the `SomeProxyMethod` seems to handle only the first value of the parameters list because the results for using: `var parameters = new SomeProxyClass() {"parameter1", "paramter2", "parameter3"};`  and `var parameters = new SomeProxyClass(); parameters.AddRange(parameters)` are different.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...

```
var items = "item1, item2, item3";
var newItems = "\"" + string.join("\",\"", items.split({","})) + "\"";
```

Comment: Sam, this outputs to :` "\"item1\"", "\"item2\"", "\"item3\""`. The value needs to be  ` "item1", "item2", "tem3"` when it is passed to `SomeProxyClass`.

Comment: ok.  well figure out how to escape a double quote in a c# string.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with this:

```
var yourString = "parameter1, parameter2, parameter3";
var result = $"\"{yourString.Replace(",",@"","")}\"";
```

Comment: This outputs to :` "\"parameter1\"", "\"paramter2\"", "\"parameter3\""` when passed to `SomeProxyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `StringBuilder` instead.

```
static class Quotes
{
    public static StringBuilder DoubleQuotes(params string[] parameters)
    {
        char quote = '\u0022';
        string value = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
        parameters[i] = 
            parameters[i]
                .Insert(0, quote.ToString()) 
                .Insert(parameters[i].Length + 1, quote.ToString());

            value += parameters[i];         
        }

    value = String.Join(", ", parameters);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(value);

    return builder;
}
```

In this case you have to change from `List<string>` to `List<StringBuilder>`. I hope this helps.

```
public void CallProxyMethod()
{
    var withHelperMethod = new SomeProxyClass()
    {
        Quotes.DoubleQuotes("parameter1", "parameter2"),
        Quotes.DoubleQuotes("parameter3")
    };

    var withoutHelperMethod = new SomeProxyClass()
    {
        new StringBuilder("\"parameter1\""),
        new StringBuilder("\"parameter2\""),
    };

    SomeProxyMethod(withHelperMethod);
    SomeProxyMethod(withoutHelperMethod);
}
```

[image: This is the result what I got]